# Lamba type is not being deduced by templated function or auto keyword

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, lambda, type-deduction

I am having a lot of trouble understanding this. I know that my compiler (Visual Studio) knows what "type" the lambda is, because sometimes it shows that it is a lambda, however my template doesn't deduce it, and neither does the auto keyword.

```
template <typename T> void templatedFunc(T (*funcPtr)(void)) { }

int main()
{
    templatedFunc([] () { return 6;} );     // Error, no template matches argument list

    int (*funcPtr)(void) = [] () { return 6;};
    templatedFunc(funcPtr);                 // Works fine

    auto p = [] () { return 6; };
    templatedFunc(p);                       // Error, no template matches

    auto p = [] () -> int { return 6; };    // Trying with explicit return type
    templatedFunc(p)                        // Error, still doesn't work
}
```

I really don't understand, any help would be great. When I hover over the variable "p" it shows its type as being int(). The only way I can make this work is by explicitly declaring a pointer like:

```
int (*ptr) (void) = [] () { return 6;};
```

The error I keep on getting is:

```
No instance of function template matches the argument list. Argument types are lambda []int () -> int
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A closure object (of an appropriate type) has an *implicit conversion* to a function pointer type, but it is not by itself a function pointer. Template argument deduction does not consider implicit conversions; the thing you have is not of a pattern that matches your function template signature.

The first code example works because *you* are performing the conversion to function pointer ahead of time.

A better way to write function templates that accept a callable is to just not use function pointers at all, but parametrize on the callable object itself:

```
template <typename T> void templatedFunc(T f) { f(); }
```

Comment: Is it the same reason why auto can't deduce the type?

Comment: @TitoneMaurice: I don't understand. `auto` deduces a type. It may just not be the type you're thinking of.

Comment: The type after "auto p = " is a lambda, my compiler tells me it's a lambda, I expected p to be a function pointer pointing to the lambda, as they're converted to function pointers.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice: They're not "converted". They are *convertible*. Big difference! The type of `p` is the type of the lambda expression, i.e. a closure type.

Answer (score 1):

You can coerce stateless lambda to function pointer with unary `+`, which will then match your function template:

```
templatedFunc(+[] () { return 6; });
```

Comment: templatedFunc(+[] () { return 6; }); doesn't work for me in Visual Studio. Is there any information on what the plus sign actually does? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

The type of object produced by this code:

```
[] () { return 6;}
```

is a class with an unutterable name (let's call it "Ftoompsk" in honour of the Young Ones)

this: `T (*funcPtr)(void)` is an object very utterable type - it's a pointer to a function accepting a void and returning a T.

Because a "Ftoompsk" does not capture any variables, it may be converted to a function pointer. However, this conversion won't take place during template argument deduction.

You could force the conversion by writing:

```
auto p = +[] () { return 6; };
templatedFunc(p);
```

Because the unary plus causes the conversion prior to argument deduction. This however, is a horrible hack which will fail the moment you modify the lambda to capture arguments.

Take Kerrek's advice. Refactor templatedFunc as shown.

Comment: auto p = +[]() { return 6; }; doesn't work for me in Visual Studio. Is there any information on what that does? I couldn't find any.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice the information is in the c++ standard. but this site is also a good source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda. Microsoft are not known for good adherence to the standard (they are improving gradually). Unless you're using VS2015 or higher I wouldn't hold out hope for good standards conformance.

Comment: MSVC's lambdas (in 32-bit, at least) have *four* conversion operators (one per calling convention) and so doesn't respond well to unary `+`.